# Why doesn't display:none hide a display:table-cell element?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use `display:none` to hide an element displayed as `display:table-cell`. I've boiled down the problematic code to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vincentpace/53hr6ztg/2/), in which `.hidden {display:none;}` works to hide a control `div` but fails to hide the `display:table-cell` `div`. How can I apply `display:none` to a `display:table-cell` `div`?

Comment: Please include you code in the question itself. Don't make us go looking. A jsFifddle is always appreciated in addition to code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that your code didn't work is because of the rule of specificity.  Read this article for details:

http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

This can be quite confusing, but I'll explain this:  `.table div {display:table-row;}` has precedence over `.hidden {display:none;}`  because styles have precedence over classes.  The reason that this works:  `.table div div.hidden{display:none;}` is because this uses styles AND classes, making IT have the higher precedence.

Basically, **whatever selecters are the most specific will have their rules applied.**

Here's how the order works:

[image: specificity order]

I hope you have at least some understanding now . . .

Let me know if you need additional help.

Answer (score 1):

try to add this to your css code:

```
.table div div.hidden{display:none;}
```

Comment: That hid it, but why doesn't the class work?  Ultimately I want to use JQuery to hide and show specific elements, so I won't be able to use a general selector like `.table div div.hidden`.

Comment: @Vincent this question is about the CSS Rule Priorities, check out this post, maybe could help you. https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/guide/w3c_guide/dom_guide/html_priorities_css.htm

Comment: I see... so that means that `.table div div` gets a specificity of 10 + 1 + 1 = 12, which beats out `.hidden`'s specificity of 10, but I can then overcome that lack by using `!important`, which I did at [this fork of the fiddle above](http://jsfiddle.net/vincentpace/qm8oy43g/). That should get me there, thanks!